# Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead

Tags: android

I'm trying to set up a toolbar with a burger menu, this is my code,and
the error is:

> This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor.
>   Do not request `Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR` and set
>   windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

The problem is that I don't know where I am getting the error from, and
also the fact that I tried everything.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    txResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txResult);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);}

// Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.


// Find our drawer view



private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                    return true;
                }
            });
}

public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
    // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on
    // position
    Fragment fragment = null;

    Class fragmentClass;
    switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_first_fragment:
            fragmentClass = MainActivity.class;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_second_fragment:
            fragmentClass = SecondActivity.class;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_third_fragment:
            fragmentClass = ThirdActivity.class;
            break;
        default:
            fragmentClass = MainActivity.class;
    }

    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

    // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
    mDrawer.closeDrawers();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<!-- This DrawerLayout has two children at the root  -->
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->
     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical">

         <include
             layout="@layout/toolbar"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

         <View
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="1dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
             android:background="#ddd"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

         <View
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="1dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
             android:background="#ddd"
             android:visibility="invisible" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/txResult"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Rezultat:"
             android:textSize="20sp"
             android:visibility="invisible" />

         <Button
             android:layout_width="207dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Scan"
             android:radius="3dp"
             android:shape="oval"
             android:width="5px"
             android:color="#1a1a1a"
             android:onClick="callZXing"
             android:id="@+id/Button"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:background="#F39C12"
             android:textColor="#ffffff"
             android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
             android:singleLine="false"
             android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" />

         <Button
             style="@style/CaptureTheme"
             android:layout_width="112dp"
             android:layout_height="68dp"
             android:text="No"
             android:id="@+id/button1"
             android:layout_weight="0.10"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:onClick="sendFirst"
             android:visibility="visible"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_marginBottom="60dp" />

         <Button
             style="@style/CaptureTheme"
             android:layout_width="112dp"
             android:layout_height="20dp"
             android:text="Yes"
             android:id="@+id/button2"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:onClick="sendSecond"
             android:visibility="visible"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_marginBottom="165dp"
             android:layout_weight="0.01" />


         <!-- The ActionBar displayed at the top -->

         <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
         <FrameLayout
             android:id="@+id/flContent"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" />
     </LinearLayout>

     <!-- The navigation drawer that comes from the left -->
     <!-- Note that `android:layout_gravity` needs to be set to 'start' -->
     <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
         android:id="@+id/nvView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
         android:background="@android:color/white"
         app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" /> </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<Activity
    android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:label="ZXing ScanBar"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
```

**Styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#673AB7</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#512DA8</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>


<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#673AB7</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>         
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#512DA8</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->    
</style>
```

**Toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">  
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Remove windowActionBar in the theme attribute and see if it works.

Comment: I added my activty, and I removed the windowActionBar,and nothing happens

Comment: Could you show me the `AndroidManifest.xml` for your `MainActivity` ?
You have currently posted the `AndroidManifest.xml` for `CaptureActivity`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need this:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Your theme parent `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` already declares that there is no action bar (but a toolbar).

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with one of my activities I had something like in the way:

In styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

In manifest.xml:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        ......

        <activity
        android:name=".ServicesActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:exported="false" />

    </application>
```